# Locating plot of 1908 burial in the Necropolis of Sydney?

Tags: australia, new-south-wales, burial-records, 1900s-decade

From his [Funeral Notice in the Sydney Morning Herald](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/14928227) that I found on Trove I know that my 2nd great grandfather Robert John Steven Sellers, who was visiting Sydney from Adelaide when he died on 18 Jan 1908, was buried at the Necropolis (in Sydney).

[image]

I would like to determine the plot number in which he is buried, in order to try and visit that grave next time I am in Sydney.

I have found a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rookwood_Cemetery) for the cemetery:

> Rookwood Cemetery (officially named Rookwood Necropolis) is the
>   largest necropolis in the Southern Hemisphere, located in Sydney, New
>   South Wales, Australia. Rookwood is a suburb, close to Lidcombe
>   railway station about 17 kilometres west of the Sydney central
>   business district.

However, I have not been able to find an online index to who is buried there.  Is there one for this, or NSW cemeteries, in general?

My fallback will be to phone the cemetery using its [Contact Us](http://www.rookwoodcemetery.com.au/index.php/contact-us) page to find the correct number.

I suspect that he will have been buried in the Presbyterian or Anglican sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked a little harder, and I am not sure whether this is new since last time I looked (I think thoroughly) but on the [Contact Us](http://www.rookwoodcemetery.com.au/index.php/contact-us) page of Rookwood Anglican & General Cemeteries there is a [Search Online](http://www.rookwoodcemetery.com.au/index.php/search-online) link at the top.

Unfortunately, it is currently reporting:

> Sorry – this feature is currently not available.

I have phoned the cemetery (02 8575 8100) and they confirmed that their online records are in the process of being implemented.

They also told me that Robert is buried in Presbyterian section 6D plot 7960.

---

The search now appears to be online at http://www.rookwoodcemetery.com.au/deceased-search-engine where I typed First Name: Robert and Last Name: Sellers to find:

```
Name                  Age Date Of Death Date Of Interment Area       Section      Grave Number
ROBERT JOHN S SELLERS 53                18/01/1908        Zone A     Presbyterian 06D 7960
```

The date of death is blank but from his death certificate, death notice and funeral notice he died on 18 Jan 1908 and his funeral was on 20 Jan 1908 so it would seem that the date of interment was more likely 20 Jan 1908 than the 18 Jan 1908 recorded here.

Comment: There seems to be an awful tendency to see death dates in what should be interment dates. One wonders where and why the errors creep in.